# When was hash chain first used?

Tags: hash, history

Hash linking is used to prove the integrity of a blockchain, or similar systems. When was that technique first used? I would guess it was early, maybe 1950s/1960s?

Answer (score 5):

Lamport suggested the use of hash chaining in 1981 in *Password Authentication with Insecure Communication*, Communications of the ACM 24.11 (November 1981), pp 770-772.

He cites 3 prior papers:

1. Diffie, W., and Hellman, M.E. New directions in cryptography.
   IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory 1T-22 (Nov. 1976), 644-654.
2. Evans, A., Kantrowitz, W., and Weiss, E. A user authentication
   scheme not requiring secrecy in the computer. Comm. A CM 17, 8
   (Aug. 1974), 437-442.
3. Wilkes, M.V. Time-Sharing Computer Systems. American
   Elsevier, New York, 1972.

[1] is the paper which essentially invented Public Key Cryptography in the open literature. Lamport refers to the use of a one way function F, as described there, as hash functions in his chain.

[2] and [3] are cited for "the widespread use of such a function", e.g., storing $y=F(x)$ instead of $x$.

So it seems to me Lamport may well be the first to suggest the use hash chaining.

**Edit:** Thanks to @Gilles for pointing out Merkle patented hash trees in 1979.

Comment: [Merkle patented hash trees in 1979](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4309569), and hash chains are a special case of that. I don't know if that special case had been used before.

Comment: what about this reference that appears here and there,
"In January 1953, Hans Peter Luhn wrote an internal IBM memorandum that used hashing with chaining. "

Comment: Interesting, but fid you forget a link/reference?  Is it maybe for storage (hashing with chaining is such a method) with a well distributed hash which is in general *not one way*?

Comment: In fact, it's in my answer to another question on general hashing. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/56404/what-was-the-first-hash-and-what-problem-was-it-supposed-to-solve/56410?r=SearchResults#56410